# how to check whether a string is palindrome or not by using recursive function

Tags: c, string, function, recursion, palindrome

I want to write a program that takes a string from input ( the size of the string is less than 100000) and then checks if it is palindrome or not. the spaces and punctuation marks should not be considered. also, it doesn't matter whether the characters are uppercase or lowercase.

print Yes if the string is palindrome and No if it's not. Plus, the function used in the program for checking if the string is palindrome or not, should be a recursive function.

e.g:

```
input1 :
radar
output1 :
Yes

iutput2 :
a man. a plan? a canal Panama
output2 :
Yes
```

so, what i have in mind is to first, delete all the characters that are not actual words and then, make all the uppercase characters lowercase so that all the words become similar in capitalization. i suppose now the string is ready to be checked with its reverse. if they are the same, it means that the string is palindrome. I have tried to write this down and here is my code. but it doesn't output correctly. what's the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int size = 100000;
void delete(char word[], int size, int element)
{
    for (int i = element; i < size; i++)
        word[i] = word[i+1];
    size--;
}
int isPalindrome(char word[], int size) 
{
    int i = 0;
    if (word[i] != word[size-1])
        return 0;
    delete(word, size, i);
    delete(word, size, size-1);
    return isPalindrome(word, size - 2);
}

int main()
{
    char word[size];
    gets(word);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] >= 65 && word[i] <= 90)
            continue;
        else if (word[i] >= 97 && word[i] <= 122)
            word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
        else
            delete(word, size, i);
    }
    if (isPalindrome(word, size) == 1)
        printf("YES\n");
    else
        printf("NO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: Note that instead of *deleting* you could just *skip* those characters. Also, `gets` was removed a couple of standard versions ago, for good reasons.

Comment: This is yet another example of people trying to teach recursion by using an inherently iterative problem.  Recursion is inappropriate for something like this.  Checking for a palindrome should run in linear time and take constant space.  A recursive version will take linear space, not to mention the overhead of all those function calls.  Now, people sometimes say "oh, but I wrote it so that my compiler should be able to recognize it as a tail-recursive call and optimize it", which is sometimes true, but the result will never be better than a simpler iterative solution.

Comment: Iterating over 100000 bytes to check "dad" is a bit wasteful

Comment: In the line `if (word[i] >= 65 && word[i] <= 90)`, I suppose the 65 is supposed to be `'A'` and by 90 you meant `'Z'`, and you really meant to write `if( isupper(word[i]))`.  Don't hard code magic numbers.  Do use standard library functions.

Comment: Similarly with `if (word[i] >= 97 && word[i] <= 122)` but OP then goes wrong with `word[i] = tolower(word[i]);` because it's already lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer doing the minimal amount of work.  The base case is string of length 0 or 1 which is a palindrome.  If the ends differ then it's not a palindrome.  Skip the head or tail if either contain the characters that isn't of interest.  Otherwise recursively case looks at what remains.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int isPalindrome(size_t len, const char s[len]) {
    if(len <= 1)
        return 1;
    unsigned char first = *s;
    if(isspace(first) || ispunct(first))
        return isPalindrome(len-1, s+1);
    unsigned char last = s[len-1];
    if(isspace(last) || ispunct(last))
        return isPalindrome(len-1, s);
    if(tolower(first) != tolower(last))
        return 0;
    return isPalindrome(len-2, s+1);
}

int main() {
    struct test {
        char *s;
        int expected;
    } tests[] = {
        {"", 1},
        {"Z", 1},
        {"D ad!", 1},
        {"mother", 0},
        {"a man. a plan? a canal Panama", 1}
    };
    for(struct test *t = tests; t < tests + sizeof tests / sizeof *tests; t++)
        printf("%s\n", isPalindrome(strlen(t->s), t->s) == t->expected ? "ok" : "fail");
}
```

and here is the corresponding output:

```
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to let the OP work their own homework exercise?  You don't have to prove to us that *you* know how to do it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger To me it was clear that op tried to solve their homework.  The delete approach makes it harder than necessary so showing a different approach along with test cases seems instructive at this point.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Revised as suggested. It's easy to forget so thanks for the reminder.